# Wordpress - "Unknown post type" when editing

Tags: wordpress

I wrote a script to add new entries into my "interactions" post type, but they don't come up in interactions, and when I manually point my browser to the ID of the post in the editor, it tells me "Unknown post type".

Heres the code I added the post with:

```
            $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_author' => '',
            'post_type' => 'interaction'
        );

        $id = wp_insert_post($new_post);``
```

The post is being created but the new entries don't show up on the interactions list and I can't edit it because it tells me its an unknown post type.

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: You have to have a title and content - and I'm not sure that empty content counts as content. Try it once with dummy content :) (e.g. "This is content", or "Lorem ipsum...") And also check whether the $title variable is empty or not.

Comment: Check if entries inserted in post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an typo in your `post_type` parameter. Change it to: `interactions` instead of `interaction`

```
<?php
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $title,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_author' => '',
    'post_type' => 'interactions'
);

$id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```